# Capturing click on anchor element within unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following dynamically generated html, an anchor, within a list item, within an unordered list, within a div:

```
<div id="id1" class="tabs vertical-tabs vertical-tabs-left"> 
<ul class="a number of classes">
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active ui-corner-left">
   <a href="#ADynamicLink" tooltip="heres a tip">Demo</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active ui-corner-left">
   <a href="#" tooltip="heres a tip">Another Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active ui-corner-left">
   <a href="#" tooltip="heres a tip">Another Link</a>
  </li>
   .... and etc
 </ul>
</div>
```

And I am using the following JQuery (1.6 yes I am unfortunately stuck with this version)

```
$(document).delegate("li", "click", function () {
    console.log("Do something on link click");
});
```

Which gives me an occasional console message only if I frantically click on the list. What is the correct combination of selector and filter to capture the click event on either the < li > or < a > element?

**UPDATE:**

Tried the following with no joy:

```
    $("ul.vertical-tab-list li").delegate("a", "click", function () {
        console.log("DoValidating on link click");
    });
```

Comment: Did you try using `"li a"`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7aL965tq/1/

Comment: I believe I did, double checking again

Comment: `$(document).delegate("li a", "click", function ()` - cause it to fire on a <td> <a></a> </td> and not on the the desired element/link

Comment: Try "li > a" for direct descendant.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace  I definitely tried that and it did not work

Comment: How does `"li a"` fire on `"td a"` ? Is the td inside of a li? Wouldn't the td have same issue with the `li` click? Remember we can only go off what you provide. Why are you delegating on the document and not on the ul?

Comment: @epascarello I'm only reporting what I'm seeing

Comment: Is there other code attached to the anchor that is stopping the propagation of the event?

Comment: @epascarello not to my knowledge but I'll check

Comment: @epascarello checked within chrome, couldn't find any attached listeneners/events

Comment: So you are using delegate because the lis/anchors are dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

Try below, you need to set `anchor` as a target for event.

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul.anumberofclasses li').delegate("a", "click", function() {
    console.log("Do something on link click");
    $('span').text('Clicked @' + new Date().toTimeString())
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span></span>
<div id="id1" class="tabs vertical-tabs vertical-tabs-left">
  <ul class="anumberofclasses">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active ui-corner-left">
      <a href="#ADynamicLink" tooltip="heres a tip">Demo</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active ui-corner-left">
      <a href="#" tooltip="heres a tip">Another Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active ui-corner-left">
      <a href="#" tooltip="heres a tip">Another Link</a>
    </li>
    .... and etc
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: And if the `<li>` is dynamically added?

Comment: @epascarello then need to take `li` to right side in selector part

Comment: @Pseudonym didnt get you, can you explain how its not working of falling short, so it would be improved

Comment: Which is like the OP originally had without the anchor?

Comment: @epascarello yes but was without `a` unlike `li > a`, also now I am bit confused what OP exctlay want

Comment: Never got the console logging

Comment: @Pseudonym Then its definitely the other code causing problem, as this code is working fine and logging on console, please check if any other script is breaking or preventing event altogether

Comment: Any specific/fancy way to find that out using chrome? I couldn't see any attached listeners

Comment: yes, chrome has breakpoint feature, use breakpoint on callback function and see if its reaching there or not. Also updated answer to show inline clicked event occurrence, do check.

Comment: It is not reaching my delegated function

Comment: then you sure there are no other event handlers attached, and also its wrapped in onready handler, right?